# How to make textbox fit container but with minwidth?

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
.SearchWrap {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.SearchInput {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;
  padding: 2px 20px 2px 4px;
  min-width: 100px;
  outline: none;
}

.StyledSearchIcon {
  height: .9em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  fill: #808080;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.Container {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="SearchWrap">
    <input aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="downshift-0-menu" aria-labelledby="downshift-0-label" autocomplete="off" id="downshift-0-input" placeholder="Filter..." class="SearchInput" value="">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" class="StyledSearchIcon"><path d="M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z"></path></svg>
  </div>
  <p>xxxx</p>
</div>
```

My `<input>` is rendering as 176px wide, but I only want it to be 100px wide (the min-width). *However,* if there's more content (more xxxx's) then the input should stretch as wide as it needs to be to fill the width of the container.

How can I do this?

I tried adding `width: auto` and various values for `flex` but I can't get it to behave the way I want.

Note that I do not know the width of `.Container`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```css
.Container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.SearchInput {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;
  padding: 2px 20px 2px 4px;
  width: 100px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  min-width:100%;
  outline: none;
}

.StyledSearchIcon {
  height: .9em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  top:4px;
  fill: #808080;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
    <input aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="downshift-0-menu" aria-labelledby="downshift-0-label" autocomplete="off" id="downshift-0-input" placeholder="Filter..." class="SearchInput" value="">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" class="StyledSearchIcon"><path d="M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z"></path></svg>
  <p>xxxx</p>
</div>

<div class="Container">
    <input aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="downshift-0-menu" aria-labelledby="downshift-0-label" autocomplete="off" id="downshift-0-input" placeholder="Filter..." class="SearchInput" value="">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" class="StyledSearchIcon"><path d="M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z"></path></svg>
  <p>xxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
</div>
```

And in case you need to keep your initial HTML you can do almost the same but you need to add `width:100%` to the search wrapper:

```css
.SearchWrap {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width:100%; /*Don't forget this*/
}

.SearchInput {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;
  padding: 2px 20px 2px 4px;
  width: 100px;
  min-width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  outline: none;
}

.StyledSearchIcon {
  height: .9em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  fill: #808080;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.Container {
  background-color: yellow;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="SearchWrap">
    <input aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="downshift-0-menu" aria-labelledby="downshift-0-label" autocomplete="off" id="downshift-0-input" placeholder="Filter..." class="SearchInput" value="">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" class="StyledSearchIcon"><path d="M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z"></path></svg>
  </div>
  <p>xxxx</p>
</div>

<div class="Container">
  <div class="SearchWrap">
    <input aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="downshift-0-menu" aria-labelledby="downshift-0-label" autocomplete="off" id="downshift-0-input" placeholder="Filter..." class="SearchInput" value="">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" class="StyledSearchIcon"><path d="M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z"></path></svg>
  </div>
  <p>xxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think answers labeled by "Try this" will not be that precious. Kindly, provide some explanations.

Comment: @ths because there is nothing to explain, all that I can do is to describe the code that anyone can understand easily by reading it. If you don't understand something you can ask what

Comment: Oh man. That width/min-width/box-sizing thing looks hacky! But it does work, so I'm not going to question it :D

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think we should take consideration of those who still trying to learn some `HTML` and `CSS` and provide for them, and for the future, a brief explanation of what's happening.

Comment: @ths what's happening is that I am using basic HTML and CSS. I don't think explaining what is width, padding, etc is the place to do here. We can easily google those properties and easily read the documentation to understand them. By the way, if you have any good/valuable explanation to add, you can do it. It's a community website so you can help improve it ;)